# postgres database table coming with spaces after each character

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, character-encoding, character, pgadmin

Today, for all the columns in my database schema (just one) (postrges), i am seeing a space being introduced after each and every character. I see that for every column that has data and this change happened to data that is 2 years old as well. This wouldn't work if that was the case before, as some validations would fail. So, seems like a bug with character encoding, i checked the client_encoding, but its showing as UTF-8 similar to the other schemas.

is this some kind of bug or if i can check anything else to check from my side ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried different clients? It might just be a text rendering issue in the client. Alternatively you could use pg_dump to make an sql script and inspect the data in that.

Comment: I did check other Clients. Same issue. I tried PgAdmin, workbench and beaver tools and they all show the same and from the actual database, the data shows incorrect

Comment: would you please copy/paste a sample of such value with such space?..

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to see how the values look if you cast them to `bytea` so that you can see the hex representation.